# Passing a string into a partial view in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'd like to be able to pass a string into my partial view from the calling View - this string will be different depending on the view from which the partial view is rendered.  Something like this:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialViews/_BreadcrumbsPartial", "New Item");}
```

Or

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialViews/_BreadcrumbsPartial", Model.Name);}
```

How can I access this second parameter from within the partial view, since I haven't labeled that parameter?  I'd like to avoid passing the whole model in if possible, and just reference that string directly.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your Partial Must bind to a string

example, at top place this:

```
@model string
```

To access the value in your partial, use `@Model` in place of string param

Comment: I tried this but don't know how to reference it in the body of my partialView.  I added exactly what you have at the top of my partial and tried @string in the body but it's looking for an identifier.

Comment: @RobVious, I updated the answer. Basically use @ Model as your string.

Comment: @Model only outputs the first string. How do I get the entire string? Eg. "testing 123" . Model will only print "testing"

Comment: @davidbenalal, that's odd. what version are you using?

Comment: I was doing @Model without the brackets " ", my bad

Comment: Here's one way to pass a string literal with the ASP.NET Core partial tag helper: <partial name='_partialName' model='new string("Value")' />

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TempData` (or possibly `ViewData`) which should be accessible in subsequent views.  However, I believe you can also pass variables directly, maybe via query string.

Please see this question as well [asp.net mvc parameter from page to a partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935915/asp-net-mvc-parameter-from-page-to-a-partial-view)

Comment: I really don't want to use ViewData - the data is already available from the ViewModel in my View.